# dynamic exclusion of files through grep matching

Tags: grep, find, echo, xargs

I have a file source-push.sh which returns the list of files which I want to exclude from the results of find command.

It looks like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find . -not \( -path './node_modules' -prune \) -name '*.js' | grep -vE $(echo $(./source-push.sh | xargs -I{} echo -n "{}|") | rev | cut -b2- | rev) | xargs -L1 standard --fix
find . -not \( -path './node_modules' -prune \) -name '*.css' | grep -vE $(echo $(./source-push.sh | xargs -I{} echo -n "{}|") | rev | cut -b2- | rev) | xargs -L1 stylelint --config stylelint.json
```

There are supposed to be a way to do the job better than that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
... | grep -vE $(echo $(./source-push.sh | xargs -I{} echo -n "{}|") | rev | cut -b2- | rev ) | ...
```

you can use the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) options `-F` and `-f`:

```
... | grep -v -F -f <( ./source-push.sh ) | ...
```

- `-F` tells grep that the patterns are fixed strings

  - (avoiding the problem that your original code would break if the patterns contain characters that are special to `grep -E`)
- `-f file` tells grep to use a list of patterns from `file`
- `<( ... )` is a bash way to present output of a program as a file (named pipe)